# Equivalent of webdriver.Chrome for RSelenium

Tags: r, rselenium

I am trying to connect Selenium in R (by using RSelenium) to an existing Chrome browser.
I can do it in Python with something like what is explained here: https://cosmocode.io/how-to-connect-selenium-to-an-existing-browser-that-was-opened-manually/

However I cannot replicate **webdriver.Chrome** in R. It works nice in Python though.

Any help?

Comment: Did you try to use firefox?